# SQL self join get only one level of parent and child

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL and need help writing the sql query.

[code snippped from here](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-self-join/)

```
SELECT
    e.first_name + ' ' + e.last_name employee,
    m.first_name + ' ' + m.last_name manager
FROM
    sales.staffs e
LEFT JOIN sales.staffs m ON m.staff_id = e.manager_id
ORDER BY
    manager;
```

[image]

In the above result i only need first level ie i want Fabiola and employees who report to Fabiola and his subordinate's subordinates.

i.e
[image]

Comment: Seems like you are looking for an rCTE (recursive Common Table Expression). Sample data and expected results (not images), will help us help you.

Comment: @Larnu thanks I am new to sql. Could I see some example using CTE?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to find all employees under each manager](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35106376/2029983)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a [recursive CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions) to do this. This will look something like:

```
WITH recCTE AS
(
    /*
     * Get top level managers (records with a null manager_id)
     * This top statement will only execute once to start the query
     */
    SELECT first_name, last_name, staff_id, manager_id, 1 as org_level
    FROM sales.staggs
    WHERE manager_id IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    /*
     * Join the CTE back to the staffs table. 
     * This statement will iterate over and over again 
     *  until the join fails. Producing more and more
     *  records.
     */
    SELECT staffs.first_name, staffs.last_name, staffs.staff_id, staffs_manager_id, recCTE.org_level + 1
    FROM recCTE
        INNER JOIN sales.staffs ON recCTE.staff_id = staffs.manager_id
    WHERE org_level < 20 /*don't go more than 20 employee deeps (just in case)*/
)
SELECT * FROM recCTE;
```